# Extract data from text file in Python and write to new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file like the one given below, and I'm looking for a way to read out all the values, and write them to a new file using Python.

```
Contact Angle (deg)     87.98
Wetting Tension (dy/cm)     2.576
Wetting Tension Left (dy/cm)    39.44
Wetting Tension Right (dy/cm)   39.44
Base Tilt Angle (deg)       0.00
Base (mm)           1.2414
Base Area (mm2)         1.2103
Height (mm)         0.5992
Tip Width (mm)          0.9480
Wetted Tip Width (mm)       0.9323
Sessile Volume (ul)     0.4752
Sessile Surface Area (mm2)  2.3382
Contrast (cts)          179
Sharpness (cts)         82
Black Peak (cts)        12
White Peak (cts)        191
Edge Threshold (cts)        86
Base Left X (mm)        3.592
Base Right X (mm)       4.835
Base Y (mm)         3.083
RMS Fit Error (mm)      4.248E-3
```

The spacing between the heading (e.g. Contact Angle (deg)) and the value is a mixture of tabs and spaces. I'm looking for a way to obtain an output file in the following format:

```
87.98
2.576
39.44
39.44
0
1.2414
1.2103
0.5992
0.948
0.9323
0.4752
2.3382
179
82
12
191
86
3.592
4.835
3.083
4.25E-03
```

It's been a while since I used Python, and even looking at similar problems, I've hit a wall and can't seem to find the answer (which I know is trivial).

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you have to use Python? This can easily be done with some bash scripting using sed/awk/cut and/or regular expressions.

Comment: Not necessarily. If there is an easier solution, I'd be more than happy to hear it. I only mentioned Python because I managed to write a fairly effective parser last year with little trouble.

Comment: What operating system are you doing this on?

Comment: Windows 7, although I've Cygwin installed and have access to gawk, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this on the sample data in the question and it works.

```
infile = open('file.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
for l in infile:
    outfile.write(l.split()[-1] + '\n')

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Just tried this code. I'm getting list index is out of range? EDIT: Sorry, the code actually does work, but the error is there. Is there a reason for the error message?

Comment: The code assumes there are no blank lines in the file. It is not possible to `split` an empty string.

Comment: Yes, there were. I've removed them since and it works perfectly. Thank you very  much for your help! Could I ask, what would the code be to skip these blank lines (if they were unavoidable)?

Comment: You would check if `l` is empty and only do the `split` if `l` is not empty. What you after that would depend on whether you wanted the blank lines in the output as well.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
# with block auto closes the files after the statements in it execute. It's good practice
with open(yourFile) as f, open(newFile, 'w') as f2:
    for line in f:
        line_out = line.split()[-1].strip()
        f2.write(line_out + '\n')
```

Comment: Why read all the lines into a list and hold it in memory? What if the input file was very large?

Comment: You have hard-coded two spaces on the third line. What if there are variable number -- the OP mentions a mixture of tabs and spaces? Also, your code does not work with the same data -- all the output is all on one line.

Comment: Thanks very much. The code is very tidy and works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = map(lambda a: a.strip().split()[-1], infile.readlines())
```

One line! Well, not exactly one line. The line above assumes that you have opened the `infile` using `infile = open("in.txt")`. And then you'll have to write it to the out file, something like `out = open("out.txt", "w"); out.writelines(answer)`

Details:

1. `a.strip().split()[-1]` splits every line by blank spaces (tabs/spaces etc) and taking the last element (number) from each line
2. `map(lambda...` part applies this to every single line of the file